# Solving Equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Hi there, 
                  hope everyone is safe, I am working on solving the equation (a+ib)^2 and finally displaying the real and imaginary parts of the answer separately. Is there a way to go about this?

Please find the code.

```
syms a b; 
c = (a+i*b)^2;
d = solve (c);
disp(imag(d));
disp(real(d));
```

Comment: What you mean by 'solving the equation'? The `solve` [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html) solves an equation for a specified variable. To solve an equation, you need an equality, but (a+i*b)^2 is not an equality. Please, clarify your question.

Comment: I mean to simplify the equation. I tried the simplify function as well but to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean: `syms a b
expand((a+1i*b)^2)`?

Comment: Yes expand the equation and then separate the real and imaginary terms.